# Linkedin tracking for single page app in Google Tag Manager

Tags: reactjs, linkedin-api, single-page-application, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to implement LinkedIn's insight tracking tag in Google Tag Manager on a single page React web application. Since there are no 'real' page reloads, the tag is only fired once. I have a dataLayer event that triggers on rerouting in the app, so I tried setting the tracking tag to fire on that event. The tag itself now fires multiple times but it does not track the new location.

What can I do to solve this?

## LinkedIn

Answer (score 1):

It is not an official solution but you can add a **custom HTML tag** including this:

```html
<script>
  lintrk("track");
</script>
```

It will be triggered by **History Change** event.

Answer (score 0):

You can fire ***Virtual pageviews on that particular dataLayer events***.

---

**What is a Virtual Pageview**

Virtual Pageviewsrefers to sending the pageview hits to Google Analytics, without reloading the page. For the single page page app, virtual pageviews are good to track the sections.

---

**Steps**

- Determine a standard notation for virtual pageview like /vpv/section name
- On the Datalayer event, push the value of section name to the website section or something that can let you know which section the user is on.
- For reporting, you can now actually see how many views happened for that particular section/page etc
- The GTM tag will be normal pageview tag, you just need to put the virtual page path value in the More settings > Basic Configuration like shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Tushar. I actually do this already. Unfortunately it does not help me in this case. The question is specific to LinkedIn's Insight Tag. I need a way for the Linkedin script to recognise a "page reload" and track it as a new page. I do a similar thing with facebook-tracking where I init the script on first page load and use "fbq('track', 'PageView')" on each "reload". But I haven't found any solution like this for linkedin.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the article [What Is Google Tag Manager? Do I Need It For My Website?](https://www.twinword.com/blog/google-tag-manager-need-website/), Google Tag Manager can listen to browser history changes, i.e. History Change is one of the pre-defined trigger in Tag Manager. So it's doable.