# How can I track each PageView event using Linkedin Pixel configuration?

Tags: angular, events, single-page-application, pageviews

I am trying to integrate `Linkedin Pixel` with my `Angular site`. I have configure like this :

Add this code in `src/index.html` file

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
_linkedin_partner_id = "<pixelId>";
window._linkedin_data_partner_ids = window._linkedin_data_partner_ids || [];
window._linkedin_data_partner_ids.push(_linkedin_partner_id);
</script><script type="text/javascript">
(function(l) {
if (!l){window.lintrk = function(a,b){window.lintrk.q.push([a,b])};
window.lintrk.q=[]}
var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
var b = document.createElement("script");
b.type = "text/javascript";b.async = true;
b.src = "https://snap.licdn.com/li.lms-analytics/insight.min.js";
s.parentNode.insertBefore(b, s);})(window.lintrk);
</script>
<noscript>
<img height="1" width="1" style="display:none;" alt="" src="https://px.ads.linkedin.com/collect/?pid=<pixelId>&fmt=gif" />
</noscript>
```

But it only fires an event once in the LinkedIn campaign. I tried to find any SDK of Linkedin through which I can directly send an event to a campaign by calling one function in the same way as Google and Facebook analytics provide but I can't find such things.

I am adding this script into index.html using `pixel.service.ts` file dynamically.
How can I send an event into the LinkedIn campaign using angular on `route change`. If anyone does that kind of work then please help me. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Potential similar questions and their solutions might help:

[Linkedin tracking for single page app in Google Tag Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44065556/linkedin-tracking-for-single-page-app-in-google-tag-manager)

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/118309/how-to-use-linkedin-pixel-event-tracking-in-single-page-application